# Read from file number of characters from a given position - C

Tags: c

I have a file called `"cache.txt"`, where I have some data. I have a  unordered_map, `cache`, with a pair of ints as value, where : the first element from the pair represents the number of characters I want to read, and the second the position from where I want to read. The key from the unordered_map, `comps`, is not relevant.

```
....
fp = fopen("cache.txt", "r");
fseek(fp, cache[comps].second, SEEK_SET);
int number_of_chars = cache[comps].first;
char c;
while((c = getc(fp)) != EOF && number_of_chars > 0) {
   --number_of_chars;
   printf("%c",c);
}
fclose(fp);
```

I have to use it several times, so that's the reason for opening and closing the file each time.

Comment: you don't have to open/close each time. Just do `fseek` on the open handle as many times you want.

Comment: This looks more like a statement than a question. Cool story. But what were you trying to ask?

Comment: Please add a concrete question.

Comment: I'm using the file for both writing and reading and I thought this is a simple to handle the task.

Comment: It does not get the info properly, is there anything missing? Is the process ok?

Comment: I don't know what you were writing, so I can't tell you what you are reading is correct.

Comment: "It does not get the info properly" is not a problem description. How not? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using text streams (and apparently you are, because you open the file in mode `"r"`, not `"rb"`), then the only position values you can pass to `fseek` are 0 or some value returned by `ftell`. In other words, you cannot count characters read yourself and use that count in a call to `fseek`.

If you use binary streams, then you can count the bytes read yourself, but you will have to deal with the fact that whatever the OS uses to represent newlines will not be translated to a newline character. Because there is no way to know how a given OS handles newlines, it's impossible to portably read a text stream in binary mode.

In short, you should take the requirement in the C standard library seriously. Make sure that the offset you are storing in your map came directly from a call to `ftell`. ("Directly" means that you cannot even use `ftell(file) + 1`; only `ftell(file)`.)

Unix/Linux programmers can get away with not dealing with the above, since Posix mandates that there is no difference between text and binary modes, and only requires that `fseek` use a value returned by `ftell` for wide streams. But if you are using Windows, you will find that trying to use `fseek` to return to a byte position you computed yourself does not work. And if you are not using Windows, you should ask yourself whether your program might someday be ported to Windows.